# Is there an easy way to verify svg/xml integrity?

Tags: xml, svg, inkscape

Problem: I use Inkscape to load an .ai file and converted to .svg file, then load from my mobile with app PainterSVG to do some editing. But PainterSVG complained the .svg does not close all xml tags properly.
Question: Is there an easy way to verify xml tags integrity? though this seems a bug in Inkscape.

The .svg file is very big and seems impossible to verify with eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xmllint to validate/format xml files.

```
xmllint --format
xmllint --valid
```